# height issues on Drop-down menu (html&css)

Tags: html, css, github, menu, header

I'm building a website on the Github page.
I started to add a drop-down menu on the header.

But, if I hover on button, the menu appears, however, I cannot click or hover on the 3rd and 4th link.

The link to code and website are written below.

[Website:](https://spoon-haruki.github.io/TechBoard/#)

[css:](https://spoon-haruki.github.io/TechBoard/styles.css)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to add the actual code next time instead of providing links but the issue for you in the **z-indexing**

as an example you can see if you add:

```
.header {z-index: 2}
.main {z-index: 1}
```

You will see that it is what you are expecting...also you might want to fix the `.dropdown-content` margin so you wont have a slight spacing break.